# Android Searchview filtering wrong on item click with ListView

Tags: java, android, searchview

I have tried other solutions. But the problem is different for me. 
I have implemented a **SearchView** with **ListView** in my app. When I search for something the first item of the array is opened **on item click**. But I need to open the same item which is listed on the search. The search result is filtering well, but onClick item is giving different item.
Please note that my question is different and not a duplicate.
My code is below:

```
public class Searchpage extends AppCompatActivity {
    SearchView searchView;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    String[] name = {
           "General Science", "Social Science", "Maths", "English", "Politics", "IT"
  };
    String[] file= {
           "science.pdf", "social.pdf", "maths.pdf", "english.pdf", "politics.pdf", it.pdf"
    };
    int[] pagenum = {
            0,0,0,0,0,0
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchpage);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.srch);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.searchlist);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent ij = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PdfView.class);
                ij.putExtra("furl", "fl/" + pagenum[position]);
                ij.putExtra("pagenm", pagenum[position]);
                startActivity(ij);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Is it your custom filter?

Comment: No! Everything is included in the same class ```Searchpage ```

Comment: Why you pass `pagenum[position]` for **furl**? Is it correct or wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all** use `ArrayList` instead of `array` to initialize `ArrayAdapter`

```
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        "General Science", "Social Science", "Maths", "English", "Politics", "IT"
));
```

**Then** use below code to find out correct `position` of your filtered data

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    int actualPosition = name.indexOf(adapter.getItem(position));

    Intent ij = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PdfView.class);
    ij.putExtra("furl", "fl/" + file[actualPosition]);
    ij.putExtra("pagenm", pagenum[actualPosition]);
    startActivity(ij);
}
```

Comment: This page number is given for opening the particular pages of each PDF. And the problem is occurring only while search filtering. It is OK when the item is opened without searching.